# there are no state metrics namespace_workload_pod and workload_type

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

there are no state metrics namespace_workload_pod and workload_type
setting up load monitoring on a kubernetes cluster, using prometheus(vmagent)
how do I get such metrics? who gives them away?

Comment: Could be that [this](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/1563) is your problem?

Comment: imperfectly,this metric should be issued using kube-state-metric. As I understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Victoria metrics, I haven't finished the scheme yet, prometheus is also suitable for a stage cluster.

I took the prometheus chart https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus

and add to values and everything worked out

```
recording_rules.yml:
 groups:
      - name: k8s.rules
        rules:
        - expr: |
            sum by (cluster, namespace, pod, container) (
              rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", image!=""}[5m])
            ) * on (cluster, namespace, pod) group_left(node) topk by (cluster, namespace, pod) (
              1, max by(cluster, namespace, pod, node) (kube_pod_info{node!=""})
            )
          record: node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate
        - expr: |
            container_memory_working_set_bytes{job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", image!=""}
            * on (cluster, namespace, pod) group_left(node) topk by(cluster, namespace, pod) (1,
              max by(cluster, namespace, pod, node) (kube_pod_info{node!=""})
            )
          record: node_namespace_pod_container:container_memory_working_set_bytes
        - expr: |
            container_memory_rss{job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", image!=""}
            * on (cluster, namespace, pod) group_left(node) topk by(cluster, namespace, pod) (1,
              max by(cluster, namespace, pod, node) (kube_pod_info{node!=""})
            )
          record: node_namespace_pod_container:container_memory_rss
        - expr: |
            container_memory_cache{job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", image!=""}
            * on (cluster, namespace, pod) group_left(node) topk by(cluster, namespace, pod) (1,
              max by(cluster, namespace, pod, node) (kube_pod_info{node!=""})
            )
          record: node_namespace_pod_container:container_memory_cache
        - expr: |
            container_memory_swap{job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", image!=""}
            * on (cluster, namespace, pod) group_left(node) topk by(cluster, namespace, pod) (1,
              max by(cluster, namespace, pod, node) (kube_pod_info{node!=""})
            )
          record: node_namespace_pod_container:container_memory_swap
        - expr: |
            kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="memory",job="kube-state-metrics"}  * on (namespace, pod, cluster)
            group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
              (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1)
            )
          record: cluster:namespace:pod_memory:active:kube_pod_container_resource_requests
        - expr: |
            sum by (namespace, cluster) (
                sum by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                    max by (namespace, pod, container, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="memory",job="kube-state-metrics"}
                    ) * on(namespace, pod, cluster) group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1
                    )
                )
            )
          record: namespace_memory:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum
        - expr: |
            kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu",job="kube-state-metrics"}  * on (namespace, pod, cluster)
            group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
              (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1)
            )
          record: cluster:namespace:pod_cpu:active:kube_pod_container_resource_requests
        - expr: |
            sum by (namespace, cluster) (
                sum by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                    max by (namespace, pod, container, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu",job="kube-state-metrics"}
                    ) * on(namespace, pod, cluster) group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1
                    )
                )
            )
          record: namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum
        - expr: |
            kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory",job="kube-state-metrics"}  * on (namespace, pod, cluster)
            group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
              (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1)
            )
          record: cluster:namespace:pod_memory:active:kube_pod_container_resource_limits
        - expr: |
            sum by (namespace, cluster) (
                sum by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                    max by (namespace, pod, container, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory",job="kube-state-metrics"}
                    ) * on(namespace, pod, cluster) group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1
                    )
                )
            )
          record: namespace_memory:kube_pod_container_resource_limits:sum
        - expr: |
            kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="cpu",job="kube-state-metrics"}  * on (namespace, pod, cluster)
            group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
             (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"} == 1)
             )
          record: cluster:namespace:pod_cpu:active:kube_pod_container_resource_limits
        - expr: |
            sum by (namespace, cluster) (
                sum by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                    max by (namespace, pod, container, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="cpu",job="kube-state-metrics"}
                    ) * on(namespace, pod, cluster) group_left() max by (namespace, pod, cluster) (
                      kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Runningstage.secr.mts-corp.ru"} == 1
                    )
                )
            )
          record: namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_limits:sum
        - expr: |
            max by (cluster, namespace, workload, pod) (
              label_replace(
                label_replace(
                  kube_pod_owner{job="kube-state-metrics", owner_kind="ReplicaSet"},
                  "replicaset", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)"
                ) * on(replicaset, namespace) group_left(owner_name) topk by(replicaset, namespace) (
                  1, max by (replicaset, namespace, owner_name) (
                    kube_replicaset_owner{job="kube-state-metrics"}
                  )
                ),
                "workload", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)"
              )
            )
          labels:
            workload_type: deployment
          record: namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel
        - expr: |
            max by (cluster, namespace, workload, pod) (
              label_replace(
                kube_pod_owner{job="kube-state-metrics", owner_kind="DaemonSet"},
                "workload", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)"
              )
            )
          labels:
            workload_type: daemonset
          record: namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel
        - expr: |
            max by (cluster, namespace, workload, pod) (
              label_replace(
                kube_pod_owner{job="kube-state-metrics", owner_kind="StatefulSet"},
                "workload", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)"
              )
            )
          labels:
            workload_type: statefulset
          record: namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel
        - expr: |
            max by (cluster, namespace, workload, pod) (
              label_replace(
                kube_pod_owner{job="kube-state-metrics", owner_kind="Job"},
                "workload", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)"
              )
            )
          labels:
            workload_type: job
          record: namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel
```